# Why should sentences not start with "there is" or "there are"?

Tags: grammar

I had written a paper with the sentence "There is also social proof in how the man with the pizza ends up with an attractive women". I had lost marks due to the fact it is poor English to start sentences with "There is" or "There are". I want to double check this is true because the prof actually is not fluent in English herself. If it true, how can such sentences be reworded? I know many things in English (and in life) aren't necessarily wrong but should be avoided. Is it that starting a sentence with "There is" is proper grammar but does not usually appear in academic writing?

I found notes with the explanation as to why she thinks this is bad:

> (Almost) never begin a sentence with “It is...” or “There is/are...”
>   These are examples of unnecessary verbiage. The exception is when the
>   “it” actually refers to something, as in “This paper is an A+. It
>   follows all the suggestions on this page.”

What is meant by when "it refers to something"?

EDIT: I personally don't see the need to quote the exact sentence as it is just an example, but I see some are getting quite worked up over the entire sentence in general.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-existent rule that sentences shouldn't start with *"There is/There are"*. @Celeritas: You didn't lose marks because of the first two words - you lost marks because ***the whole sentence is bad English***.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever that starting a sentence with “there is/are” should not be grammatically correct, good, clear, concise English. The sentence you quoted from your essay is not clear or concise, but it grammatically impeccable.

Comment: Care to elaborate why the sentence is so bad? Out of context I don't expect it to make much sense. Since the comment made was explicitly about not starting sentences with "There is" would you recommend I argue against the deduction of marks?

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. *It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.* - Jane Austen, Pride and Prejudice (1813)

Comment: *It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.* - George Orwell, 1984 (1949)

Comment: *It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair.* - Charles Dickens, A Tale of Two Cities (1859)

Comment: *There was a boy called Eustace Clarence Scrubb, and he almost deserved it.* - C. S. Lewis, The Voyage of the Dawn Treader (1952)

Comment: *It was the day my grandmother exploded.* - Iain M. Banks, The Crow Road (1992)

Comment: *It was love at first sight.* - Joseph Heller, Catch-22 (1961)

Comment: @F.E. It was a dark and stormy night, and the rain fell in torrents... In the hands of a good writer, *there* may begin a great sentence. *More often than not*, it is a lazy way to begin an argument or a statement.

Comment: And, to be fair, those are examples of creative writing.

Comment: @Susan: It seems unlikely to me that anyone could establish a statistical correlation between "lazy" writing and starting sentences with **It/There is/are**. The idea that some half-witted teacher should actually be giving OP this "rule" in order to improve his writing skills both boggles and beggars belief. He could improve far more by finding a different teacher.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - a statistical correlation is impossible because you do not have the entire body of terrible writing at your disposal. Have you ever taught grammar and composition? I don't say his teacher is correct in stating "rules", but guidelines help the average writer more than they hinder.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "It should be noted that there is nothing for us to fear but fear itself." "It was the first thing God said in the beginning: there should be light." "There is a difference between men and women, madam, but I can't conceive of what it is."

Comment: @F.E. As nxx said, your examples are off base because they come from creative writing and the phrasings are used for style. In academic writing the goal is not style (although it can be a nice touch) the goal is clarity.

Comment: @Tonik: There are times when rewording a sentence to avoid the use of "there is" or "there are" can reduce clarity. Or should I have said: *"Clarity is often reduced when sentences are reworded to avoid the use of 'there is' or 'there are'"*? Or *"Rewording sentences to avoid the use of 'there is' and 'there are' often results in the concomitant reduction of clarity"*?

Comment: Absolutely. I agree, as I have already said in my answer. I don't think there+BE should be avoided, Celeritas' teacher does. Please read what I've written before trying to contradict me ;)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I think your question is very interesting.

I wouldn't say sentences should not start with "there is" or "there are", because it's not a rule per se.

That said, good academic writing is about **making your point as clearly and efficiently as you can**. Furthermore, in academic english good sentences are **short/simple sentences** (contrary to other languages such as french, where complex sentences are used a lot in academic writing and seem to reflect the author's skills and depth). This is a tacit rule of the language that's a real challenge for english teachers (in France at least) because most of the time it's hard to diagnose. Personally it took me a long time to understand this, as my teachers were never able to explain what was wrong. They just did the same as yours : criticize the use of an otherwise correct phrasing that made my sentence more complex than needed.

"There is" is a neutral phrasing that (in some cases) steals importance from the real subject of the sentence. In your example, using it makes your sentence less clear and understandable. Plus it seems to show that **you don't know how to use "social proof" in a sentence**, specifically because you had to *twist* your sentence and make it more complicated in order to talk about "social proof".

Your sentence should probably have started with its natural subject, which is **the way the man acted**.

---

EDIT :

> What is meant by when "it refers to something"?

"It" can refer to a previously mentionned object, but it's not always the case.
In the same spirit, "there" can refer to a previously mentionned place, but it's not always the case either.

Here are some examples :

> *The chair* is big, **it** takes too much space.

Here, "it" is used so that "the chair" doesn't have to be said again. But the subject of the second proposition is still the chair. What takes too much space? -> the chair.
The sentence could get rid of the word "it", and become :

> The chair is big, the chair takes too much space.

In the following, "it" refers to a proposition:

> The chair is big, **it** is impossible *to put anything else in the room*.

Here, "it" refers to the action described later. What's impossible? -> not the chair!
The sentence could get rid of the word "it", and become :

> The chair is big, putting anything else in the room is impossible.

Now "it" becomes indispensable when it doesn't refer to any clear object/proposition:

> **It**'s time to go!

It doesn't refer to anything in particular. What is time? -> ???

"There" works kind of the same way. When you say :

> I entered *the room* and **there** was the teacher.

Where was the teacher? -> In the room I entered.

But "there +BE" can be used without a context :

> There are several ways to use this word.

Where are several ways? -> ??? anywhere, everywhere, that's not the point.

**What your quote is saying is that "it" and "there" should only be used when they refer to something.**

I can't completely agree on this, here's why :

In my last example, you could say "This word can be used in several ways" in order to get rid of "there are". But the sentence becomes passive, which is less simple/natural than the original one.

Clarity is not only brought via shortness of sentences, elimination of neutral words etc. Active tense is much more simple and straightforward than passive tense, and sometimes active tense should prevail over the choice of non-neutral words like "there".

The best way to know whether or not your sentence is as clear as it can be is to try different phrasings and see how they feel. **Trying different ways of expressing yourself will make you learn faster, and give you a real chance to pass your message**.

For instance, I have corrected this answer several times as I was writing it, finding more efficient phrasings after one or two trials. My goal is for you to understand what I am saying, and sometimes the first words I write are not the perfect ones. Success doesn't come from luck, it comes from repeated failures. Leaving your first choice of phrasing on the page is ignoring the very true fact that you have great potential but the first trial can almost always be perfected.

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: And to clarify what the teacher seemingly meant about the exception (as she does not use "it is" or "there is/are"): after starting with "The way the man ...", the next sentence, referring back to this, could begin "There are", eg, "The way the man handed the women the pizza shows his attitude toward them. There are many good ways to hand pizza to a woman...."

Comment: @Susan thanks :)
nxx : Yes, that seems to be a good way of correction the clumsiness of the original sentence. I find that most of the time in english if the sentence is not working it should be decomposed into two sentences ;)

Comment: "in academic english good sentences are short/simple sentences" what makes you say this? I can think of quite a few pieces of academic writing that have more complex sentences compared to fiction.

Comment: I said that in comparison with other languages, specifically french. In english, complex building of a sentence should only be used when necessary whereas in french complexity is almost a goal in itself, because it makes the idea described look more complex and the more complex the idea, the more respect is given to the author. In english it's the opposite : if the idea looks complex it means you didn't express yourself as well as you could have.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still unclear. Doesn't the tendency to use complex sentences or simple sentences have more to do with culture and isn't inherent in a language itself? So you're saying in English if a piece of writing is complex, the author did a poor job writing it? What if the subject being discussed is complex? Why would other languages try to write in a complex fashion, doesn't that defeat the purpose of trying to be understood?

Comment: To answer your comment's first question, it seems to me that language is cultural and has rules that evolve in time, and change from place to place. Personally I can't consider a language without its cultural aspect.
For your second and third questions : As I said previously, complex sentences "should be used when necessary". What I meant was when the subject being discussed is too complex to do otherwise.
For your last question : yes absolutely, writing in a complex fashion defeats the purpose of trying to be understood, I completely agree. The fact is it is a tendency in french.

Comment: "Why should sentences not start with “there is” or “there are”" - that's very strange. Is that true only about academic English? How would you say "there is a table in the room" without using "there is"?

Comment: I didn't say that sentences should not start with "there is" or "there are", Celeritas' teacher said that.
As I said at the end of my response, sometimes not using "there is/are" for no other reason makes the sentence more awkward than necessary. In your example, you could say "the room contains a table" but it's weird, and unless the context requires such a phrasing, you would say "there is a table in the room".

Comment: *"Active tense is much more simple and straightforward than passive tense, and sometimes active tense should prevail over the choice of non-neutral words like "there"."* -- In today's English, what is the "**active tense**" that you mentioned?

Comment: Active : I can use this word.  
Passive : This word can be used (by someone)  
In passive tense the object of the sentence becomes a passive subject. Active and passive can be applied to any tense, present past and future.

Comment: You need to insert "@F.E." into your comment if you want me to be notified. Back to my original question, what is this "**active tense**" that you talk about, can you provide a link to or excerpt from a grammar source that defines it? Also, can you provide a link to a grammar source that explains what a "*non-neutral word*", e.g. "there", actually is? -- I'm asking these questions because you're using grammar terminology that I'm not familiar with, and I'd like to know where you're getting your grammar from.

Comment: @F.E. Here's a link : http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html which is the first Google result for "english grammar active passive" search. I don't have my own reference because I learnt all this in school. The "neutral" aspect of there (when it doesn't refer to a place) was my own formulation of what I was trying to say. I don't know whether an official term exists or not.

Comment: Okay, it's an EFL website. Just to let you know, their grammatical terminology is wrong. Today's English has a system of voice: *active voice*, and *passive voice*. "Active voice" and "passive voice" are not verb forms, and they are not "tenses". This thread had also brought up the issue of the use of dummy pronouns as subject, and this type of usage occurs in certain types of information packaging constructions: *existential*, *extraposition*, and *it-cleft*. You might be interested in those topics. Those types of constructions are often involved in discourse, written and oral.

Comment: @F.E. as I said I didn't use this website, I merely found one for you because you asked. I've studied grammar thoroughly but although I'm fluent in english I'm not a native and I don't know all the english grammar terminology. In french these are just called 'actif' and 'passif' (no word afterward!). The fact is I wasn't trying to please an expert such as you, I was trying to help the person who asked the question ;) I will try to perfect my vocabulary.  
Thank you for the precisions, I do find them very interesting, if you have a good website for me to look them up, bring it on! :)

Answer (score 2):

My only response is: indeed, your professor is not fluent in English, to have stated such baloney about English grammar!

Your sentence is grammatical but sloppy English.

Comment: read the answer below. **There** is an empty word, which weakens a statement. Grammar alone does not guarantee good style, a good sentence, or a strong statement.

Comment: Empty words do not "weaken" a statement, any more than auxiliary verbs or articles do. That's just a crochet. How would you ask "Is it raining?" without using the empty _there_?

Comment: [_There_-Insertion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/there-levin.pdf), the rule that inserts the dummy subject _there_, is obligatory for some verbs (_seem, appear_), and very common with long subject clauses whenever they are the subject of the verbs in the list.

Comment: @Susan: Oh damn. I meant "the empty _it_," of course. Skitt's Rule strikes again 8|

Comment: @JohnLawler - Of course, some sentences are best started (or only possible) using *there/it*. But *There is also social proof in how the man with the pizza ends up with an attractive women* certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: _An attractive women_ is indisputably not English, @Susan.

Comment: @anongoodnurse ""There is also social proof in how the man with the pizza ends up with an attractive women""  <-- if he removes the word "there" he gets "is also social proof in how the man with the pizza ends up with an attractive women""  So how can "there" be an "empty word"?